# Custom section separator for Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to add a section separator for `Navigation Drawer` with this code which is working but I want to customize it like this example :

[**example**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUwVx.png)

xml code :

```
  <group
        android:id="@+id/menu_center"
        android:checkableBehavior="none">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/Fragment_R"
            android:icon="@mipmap/r"
            android:title="@string/r" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/Fragment_t"
            android:icon="@mipmap/t"
            android:title="@string/t" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/Fragment_Re"
            android:icon="@mipmap/real"
            android:title="@string/Real" />
    </group>
```

Answer (score -1):

You Needs To Create A Drawable Resource  File Like This.

drawer_items_bg

```js
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#363636" />
        </shape>
    </item>


    <item android:top="2dp" android:right="-2dp" android:left="-2dp" android:bottom="-2dp" >
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#363636" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#777776" />
        </shape>

        android:dashGap="10px"
                android:dashWidth="10px"

    </item>



</layer-list>
```

Then Add It In Your NavigationView

```js
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemTextColor="#FFF"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item_bg"  //you need to add as background here
        app:itemIconTint="#FFF"
        android:textSize="22sp"/>
```

Hope That will works great!